# Cosa sono i "passi di lupo"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Uscì, recando come
>   sempre la lucerna e lasciando me alla luce del fuoco; attesi un
>   istante, poi mi levai anch'io silenziosamente. Oltrepassata la solita porta, prese in direzione della cucina, ma girò prima verso dritta per stanze e stanzini sconosciuti; io dietro a **passi di lupo**.

La mia domanda è sulla locuzione "passi di lupo" in questo passaggio. Si tratta di un modo di dire? Ho cercato alle voci "lupo" e "passo" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa espressione.

Comment: Considerato quello che leggo della scena, potrebbe significare sia silenzioso che veloce, senza perdere tempo (o magari entrambi)

Comment: A me sembra più significare a passo lento e circospetto per non fare rumore, come un lupo che vuole sorprendere una preda.

Comment: Anche in questo caso, non è un modo di dire. Sono anch’io del parere che significhi “a passo lento e circospetto”.

Comment: Nel *Re del mare* di Salgari si trova: “Si erano fermati, non osando inoltrarsi sotto la foresta o s’avanzavano a passi di lupo per sorprenderli?”

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @DavidMather!

Answer (score 4):

Ho fatto una ricerca trovando vari testi di autori che attestano 'passi di lupo' o 'passo di lupo', per esempio nel commento dell'autobiografia di Henri Cartier-Bresson su Repubblica:

> Ora i testi riuniti in *L'immaginario dal vero* sono appunto un
>   confronto tra fotografia e disegno, ma in forma di autobiografia. Da
>   fotografi, si entra nell' evento da intrusi; "per non intorbidare l'
>   acqua prima di pescare", bisogna accostarsi **a passi di lupo**.

Qui Verga:

> Poi si avanzò **a passi di lupo** fin sotto la finestra della cugina. Trattavasi adesso di picchiare quei tre famosi colpi, promessi quando ci volevano ancora due ore per picchiarli, quando il cuore, sotto gli occhi di lei, picchiava più forte...

È la stessa cosa di "in punta di piedi". Forse, trattandosi di lupo, può trasmettere un senso di maggiore bellicosità, o l'intento di catturare una preda.

Tra le curiosità, "passo di lupo" è usato anche in senso geografico ("là dove passa il lupo"), di solito scrivendolo "passo del lupo"; era il soprannome di un bandito riformato in Puglia di cui parla Charles MacFarlane nelle 'Vite di Banditi', tale Luca; ed è una delle traduzioni del nome tedesco "Wolfgang".